# solution of system of equations

Tags: matrices, number-theory, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

Is it decidable when the following system of equation has solutions over the integers?

$$
\begin{matrix}
x_1y_2-x_2y_1=a_1,\\
x_1y_3-x_3y_1=a_2,\\
x_2y_3-x_3y_2=a_3.
\end{matrix}
$$

Here $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ are integers which $GCD(a_1,a_2,a_3)=1$  and $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$ are variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using $x_1=0$, $x_2=-1$, $x_3=-1$, $y_1=a_1$,  $y_2=a_2$ and $y_3=a_2-a_3$, you have a solution.

Comment: This is a trivial solution. Always interesting when the solutions are written as a formula.